# How do I send a command to a specific buffer?

Tags: vim

If I have a buffer's name + number (it might even be hidden), how do I send a command to it while keeping the focus on my active buffer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't; instead, that hidden buffer must be (temporarily) activated in order to execute commands on it.

(The only exceptions are the `getbufline()` and `get/setbufvar()` functions, but you can't do much with them.)

My [ingo-library plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4433) provides a handy `ingo#buffer#visible#Execute( bufnr, command )` function that handles that for you.